# calculating Longitude and Latitude of current location

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the latitude and Longitude of current users location. I have the following code below, but for some reason Latitude and Longitude does not return anything. Is it because geoLocation is not supported on my phone or any other reason. I am developing this code in windows on android based phone.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

The location on my phone is turned on. Below is the picture of the phone:

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is how my androidmanifest.xml file looks like.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.goomaps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to enable geolocation first as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html)

Comment: the code seems to be correct, check whether you turned on location services on your phone

Comment: Thank you Pritish. making changes in androisdmeanisfest file worked . I could not see the changes right away. I need to power off the phone and switch it on and I can see the longitude and latitude.